# Send Email Only when radio option is Selected

Tags: php, email, if-statement, opencart

I am modifying a registration form to include two radio buttons for the account type the customer is applying for.
So I have two new buttons: Personal Account []   Corporate Account [].

If the customer selects personal account, value "1" is saved to a new column in my customer table (account_type), and if corporate account is selected, the value "0" is saved.
 Now, what I want to do is to modify the code below that sends an email to admin every time a new customer registers so that it sends an extra email if a customer has applied for a Corporate account.

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
$mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
$mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
$mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
$mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');
$mail->setTo($data['email']);
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setSender($this->config->get('config_name'));
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setText($message);
$mail->send();

**// Send to main admin email if new account email is enabled**
if ($this->config->get('config_account_mail')) {
    $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->send();
    // Send to additional alert emails if new account email is enabled
    $emails = explode(',', $this->config->get('config_alert_emails'));
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        if (strlen($email) > 0 && preg_match('/^[^\@]+@.*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i', $email)) {
            $mail->setTo($email);
            $mail->send();
        }
    }
}
```

The code above after "//send to main admin if new account email is enabled" just sends a simple email to admin saying someone new has registered. I want to keep that, but I would like to send the extra email if someone is applying for a corporate account. I guess I just need to use an if statement to check whether account_type=0 but I am not an expert and I don't know how to integrate that to the existing code. I hope I have explained myself well. By the way, all this code is from Open Cart, open-source e commerce system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use if condition like

```
if(isset($_POST['ur_radio_ele_name']) && $_POST['ur_radio_ele_name']!=''){
  // your code to send mail
}
```

if `$_POST['ur_radio_ele_name']` is set and not null then only it would send mail, otherwise it wont.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help. Thought I haven't been able to integrate this code successfully, I tried adding the following code, but it didn't work.  `code`                                                   //Starts corporate account email to admin mod
  if(isset($_POST['account_type)']) && $_POST['account_type)']!=''){
$mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
$subject = ($this->request->post['account_type']) ? 'New Personal Account' : 'New Corporate Account'  . ' ' . 'Registration: ' .$this->request->post['firstname'] . ' ' . $this->request->post['lastname'];
$mail->send();
}`code`

Comment: @codekmarv, I have corrected above code and it should work now. When the form has radio element, when the form is post the $post array with key as name same as radio element name is set only when the radio element is selected otherwise $_POST key is not set. Check that you have given name to that radio element and in post you are checking for the same $POST key.

Comment: Thanks for your help, will try this and will report later